# Angular - navigate back from detail component

Tags: angular, typescript, routeparams

I have a page '/categories' showing multiple categories which the user can click on. When a category is clicked, the detail page is shown with the id of the category shown in the url '/categories/1'.

To achieve this I configured my app routing module the following way:

```
{
    path: `${locale}/categories`,
    component: CategoriesComponent
  },
  {
    path: `${locale}/categories/:id`,
    component: CategoryDetailComponent
  }
```

I navigate to the detail page with the following code:

```
this.router.navigate([getLocaleFromStorage(), category.id]);
```

The problem is that when I'm on the detail page and I go back in the browser I am being sent to the page '/categories/categories' instead of just '/categories'.

My first thought was to overwrite the back navigation, but I haven't found a good way to do this yet. I have found an article that explains how to implement this kind of structure, but they add a back button to the page and navigate back to the correct page on click of the button. This would work, but the user would still be sent to the '/categories/categories' page if just using the browser's back button.

Is there any good way to achieve what I want?

[The article I was speaking about](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular-passing-parameters-to-route/)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does you  method look like `getLocaleFromStorage`?

Comment: that method works fine, it's just the back navigation

Comment: How do you currently navigate back?

Comment: I didn't implement back navigation because I don't know if it's a good practice nor how to do it. I noticed the problem while using the browser's back button.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.

Instead of

```
this.router.navigate([getLocaleFromStorage(), category.id]);
```

I should have used

```
this.router.navigate([getLocaleFromStorage()+'/categories', category.id]);
```

Because I was providing an url that didn't exist, the route was redirected to the categories page by the App routing module.